# Fully stretching pattern

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, scale, swatches, size

I defined a simple pattern that consists just of vertical lines that repeat with a specific distance.
Now I want these lines to always stretch from the top to the bottom of the element that uses it as fill.
The lines should also become narrower from bottom to top.
Can this be done with an Illustrator pattern swatch - or do I have to define the lines manually?

Here is an example with the lines distorted using a distortion envelope:
[image: distorted, intended result]

The lines themselves are straight but changed by the distortion later.
[image: source pattern to be distorted, currently the lines don't narrow]

The lines should become more narrow because without becoming narrower, they aren't visually differentiable anymore towards the top as they are too wide to look like individual lines.
[image: first attempt]

Comment: Could you please post some images so we can see how the patterns looks and how you want it to stretch?

Comment: I somewhat think if you need a shape of tapering curved paths which maintain spacing between them, then distorting a *pattern* may not be the best method. i.e. a collection of thin tall triangles, then add a curve... But I'm having trouble following this question.

Comment: You probably need to expans the strokes first